# Python 3 - importing subpackage submodule names into top package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a Python repo with the following package structure:

```
inttools/
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── complex
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── complex.py
├── divisors
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── divisors.py
├── primes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── primes.py
├── sequences
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── champernowne.py
│   ├── collatz.py
│   ├── general.py
│   └── ulam.py
├── special_numbers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── hilbert.py
│   └── polygonal.py
├── special_sets
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cyclic.py
│   └── polygonal.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
```

In each of the subpackage `__init__.py`s I'm importing the submodule names using `from .<submodule name> import *`, e.g. in `utils.__init__.py` we have

```
from .utils import *
```

and now in the main package `inttools.__init__.py` I am importing all the subpackage submodule names in the following way:

```
from utils import *
from primes import *
...
...
```

The idea is that when the `inttools` package is imported all subpackage submodule names are available in the package namespace, but this fails. For example in iPython I `cd` to the directory in which `intttools` lives (`/Users/srm/dev`) and do the following.

### In [1]: import inttools

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-52c9cc3419fb> in <module>()
----> 1 import inttools

/Users/srm/dev/inttools/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from utils import *
      2 from primes import *
      3 from divisors import *
      4 from complex import *
      5 from sequences import *

ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: `from .utils import *`, `from .primes import *`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is `inttools`, therefore subpackages are `inttools.utils`, `inttools.primes` etc.

You can either use this absolute path in `__init__.py`, or relative path (`.utils`, `.primes` etc.)